# Merge arrays with control of array position

Tags: php

I have two random arrays merged, everything displaying/functioning beautifully.  The one stuck I have is this:

When I merge the two arrays together I need to make sure that every 3 item comes from array2.

```
array1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k)
array2 (a1,a2,a3,a4)
```

**My desired outcome:**

`d  k  c  a1  j  i  g  a2`   etc.

**What I have done so far:**

```
function randomize_blocks($arr, $num = 1) {
shuffle($arr);

$r = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $r[] = $arr[$i];
}
return $num == 1 ? $r[0] : $r;
}
 //gather donor blocks into an array
 $donorBlocks = array($blockA, $blockB, $blockC, $blockD, $blockE, $blockF, 
 $blockG, $blockH, $blockI, $blockJ, $blockK, $blockL, $blockM, $blockN, 
  $blockO);

//gather value blocks into an array
$valueBlocks = array($valueA, $valueB, $valueC, $valueD);

 //shake that shuffler real hard! DT
$shuffled_valueBlocks = randomize_blocks($valueBlocks, 4);
 $shuffled_donorBlocks = randomize_blocks($donorBlocks, 15);

//combine our shuffled arrays together
$combinedArrays = array_merge($shuffled_valueBlocks, $shuffled_donorBlocks);

 //shuffle them all together!
 $shuffled_blocks = randomize_blocks($combinedArrays, 19);

 //display bocks on page
  foreach ($combinedArrays as $key => $value) {
     echo $value;
  }
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: what is your expected outcome you want after merge? please post that too.Also what you tried so far?

Comment: Editing post now.

Comment: eery time 8 values will outcome?

Comment: No the grand total is 19. 4 value blocks, 15 donor blocks

Comment: you have total 15 values from both array ten how you will get 19. i am out of logic.can you please give clearance?

Comment: There is 19 total.
$shuffled_valueBlocks = randomize_blocks($valueBlocks, 4);
 $shuffled_donorBlocks = randomize_blocks($donorBlocks, 15);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the assumption that you want both arrays shuffled as well as placed in your desired pattern:

```
$array_one = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k');
$array_two = array('a1','a2','a3','a4');

function merge_random_interval($array_one = array(), $array_two = array(), $interval = 3) {
    $return_array = array();

    // Shuffle the arrays - that seems to be important?
    shuffle($array_one);
    shuffle($array_two);

    // Go through the first array
    $array_two_index = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_one); $i++) {

        // Every $interval add a value from the second array
        if ($i > 0 && $i % $interval == 0) {

            // Make sure there is a value in the second array
            if (isset($array_two[$array_two_index])) {
                $return_array[] = $array_two[$array_two_index];
                $array_two_index++;
            }
        }

        $return_array[] = $array_one[$i];
    }

    // You may want to check if $array_two has more values that weren't added?
    // Compare $array_two_index against count($array_two)

    return $return_array;
}

$result_array = merge_random_interval($array_one, $array_two, 3);

echo implode(' ', $result_array); // g d c a1 h i j a4 b e a a2 k f
```

Comment: That appears to be what I have been looking for!  Testing out now.

Comment: @Johanna  none of the answer will give you 19 values (as you said in comment):-https://eval.in/852160

Comment: @neuromatter I appreciate your help! Brilliant! You saved the day!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way with `array_splice` to modify the longest of the two arrays into the desired result:

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

foreach ($a as $i => $v) 
   array_splice($b, $i*4+3, 0, [$v]);
```

`$b` will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 4, 5, 6, 'b', 7, 8, 9, 'c', 10, 11, 12, 'd', 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Thank you for posting elegant solution! This will be a nice landing page for those stuck in a similar position as I.

Comment: oh best solution among all, but come a bit late.+1 BTW @trincot

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this?

```
$a1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'];
$a2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'];


$a = [];
shuffle($a1);

foreach ($a1 as $k => $v) {
    $a[] = $v;
    if (($k + 1) % 3 === 0 && $a2) $a[] = array_shift($a2);
}
```

Comment: My goodness is that beautiful. Let me tinker with it now and advise.

Comment: @Johanna  none of the answer will give you 19 values (as you said in comment):-https://eval.in/852159

Comment: @AlivetoDie This example can't output 19 values since there aren't 19 input values to shuffle together. It does when `$a1` has 15 items, though.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i know. I am just telling to OP  because when i asked outcome then she said it have to be 19, and for that 19 values needed

Comment: @AlivetoDie I think the outcome of 19 wasn't based on the original example input of a-k. Since she said "4 value blocks, 15 donor blocks", that sounds like a different input than what was shown in the example.

Comment: I updated the example later to show the two arrays in their entirety. Sorry for the confusion.